# Where did the Hardware Keyboard Present go in Android Studio 0.8.14 Virtual Device Configuration?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

In the lastest version of Android Studio (0.8.14) it has a great new wizard for creating/configuring an AVD.  However, two key things have been removed:

1. Hardware Keyboard Present
2. and the ability to choose some pre-existing/default skins

Does anyone know if this is a bug or what to do instead?  I'd like to be able to type using my keyboard into the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting **New Hardware Profile** when creating or editing your AVD will bring up a dialog box which has a check box titled **Has Hardware Keyboard**.

With regard to skins if you go to the **Default Skin**  directory search and go to `{Your Android SDK Location}\tools\lib\emulator\skins` then you should be able to see a dynamic skin option.

Presumably this is the folder where you should be able to add new device skins, although I'm not sure exactly where the greater range of default skins are.

Comment: I also found that I can bring up the one built into the SDK using:  
<pre>
android avd
</pre>
which still has these options.

Comment: @Joel I checked the 'Has Hardware Keyboard' check box, but nothing appeared in the virtual device. How can I make the Hardware Keyboard or Hardware Keys make appear ?

Comment: The hardware keyboard means that you can use your physical keyboard to add input in the emulator. If you want to use both your hardware keyboard and the virtual keyboard then you can go into the settings while running the emulator.
Settings -> Language & Input -> Go to the "Keyboard & Input Methods -> enable default

Comment: @Joel Will you describe the steps to enable hardware keys during the making of a new virtual device ?